# Loss of certain values when using dict and expand together in Snakemake

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have try to use a function to return a dict as a rule input, here is a simple expamle:

```
# debug.smk
input_a='/{output}/to/{group_name}/input_a'
input_b='/{output}/to/{group_name}/input_b'

rule_a=True
rule_b=True

output='output'
group_name='group_name'

def get_rule_output(): 
    output={}
    if rule_a: 
        output['output_a']=expand(input_a, output=output, group_name=group_name)
        print(expand(input_a, output=output, group_name=group_name))
    if rule_b: 
        output['output_xx']=expand(input_b, output=output, group_name=group_name)

    print(output)
    
    return output

rule all: 
    input: 
        get_rule_output(),
```

I use following command to run it

```
snakemake -s debug.smk
```

My expected:

`get_rule_output()` return a dict with two output

```
{'output_a': ['/output_a/to/group_name/input_a'], 'output_xx': ['/output_a/to/group_name/input_b']}
```

however, its return value is

```
{'output_a': [], 'output_xx': ['/output_a/to/group_name/input_b']}
```

debug output by print() is following

```
snakemake -s snakemake/debug.smk
['/output_a/to/group_name/input_a']
{'output_a': [], 'output_xx': ['/output_a/to/group_name/input_b']}
Building DAG of jobs...

#other snakemake debug output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename `output={}` inside your function:

In your code `output` has two meanings:

- `output='output'` which is also the value you want to use in `expand(...)`
- `output={}` which is the dictionary you want to hold your results, but which you are using in your `expand(...)` instead

Due to the local scope, `output={}` is used instead of `output='output'` for your `expand(...)` statement.

This works

```py
# debug.smk
input_a = "/{output}/to/{group_name}/input_a"
input_b = "/{output}/to/{group_name}/input_b"

rule_a = True
rule_b = True

output = "output"
group_name = "group_name"


def get_rule_output():

    d= {}

    d["output_a"] = expand(input_a, output=output, group_name=group_name)
    d["output_b"] = expand(input_b, output=output, group_name=group_name)

    print(d)

    return output


rule all:
    input:
        get_rule_output(),
```

Answer (score 1):

The choice of variable names is unfortunate. There are two variables  `output`, one is used for the output and another one is defined in the workflow as:

```py
output='output'
```

This leads to circularity in variable expansion. Fixing the names should resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, I have replace it with `output='test' group_name='group'`, but, its seems also not work

Comment: oh, I got that, Its because I use `output` as local variable in function